# Update value on Recyclerview click listener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

i develop app using firebase to upload files and view it in Recyclerview 
when i click on any item should take me to another activity and view the file in webView the issue is when i click on any item take the first file uploaded to firebase , i need when i click in any item take the file for this item

```
public class postShows extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView postlist;
    private DatabaseReference mdatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    ImageView imagepostl;
    TextView textname;
    String  ma,mmmmmm;
    PostUtils m;


    Context context;
    public static String imageURL, fileType,fileNAme;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_shows);
        mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(PostNew.item);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        imagepostl = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagefilesource);
        textname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textfilename);
        postlist = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.postRecycle);
        postlist.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        postlist.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PostUtils, PostViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new
                FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PostUtils, PostViewHolder>(
                        PostUtils.class,
                        R.layout.post_row,
                        PostViewHolder.class,
                        mdatabase


                )

                {


                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, PostUtils m, int position) {
                        fileType = m.getfiletype();
                        fileNAme=m.getFileName();

                        //   viewHolder.setDesc(m.getDescription());
                        if (m.getfiletype().equals("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")) {
                            // imagepostl.setImageResource(R.drawable.word);
                            viewHolder.setFileName(m.getFileName());
                            viewHolder.setWord(imagepostl);
                            mmmmmm= viewHolder.setImageURL(ma,m);

                        } else if (m.getfiletype().equals("application/pdf")) {
                            viewHolder.setFileName(m.getFileName());
                            viewHolder.setPDF(imagepostl);
                            mmmmmm= viewHolder.setImageURL(ma,m);


                        } else if (m.getfiletype().contains("image")) {

                            viewHolder.setimage(imagepostl);
                            mmmmmm= viewHolder.setImageURL(ma,m);


                        } else {
                            viewHolder.setFileName(m.getFileName());
                            {
                                viewHolder.setimage(imagepostl);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        PostViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
                        viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new PostViewHolder.ClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Kasittestbank.getAppContext(), Kasit.class);
                                intent.putExtra("imageURL",mmmmmm);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                Kasittestbank.getAppContext().startActivity(intent);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                                Toast.makeText(Kasittestbank.getAppContext(), "Item long clicked at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        });
                        return viewHolder;
                    }
                };

        postlist.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }


    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

        View mview;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        FileOpen fileOpen;


        public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mview = itemView;
            mview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());

                }
            });
        }

        private PostViewHolder.ClickListener mClickListener;

        //Interface to send callbacks...
        public interface ClickListener {
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

            public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
        }

        public void setOnClickListener(PostViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener) {
            mClickListener = clickListener;
        }



        public void setFileName(String name) {

            TextView textName = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.textfilename);
            textName.setText(name);


        }



        public void setWord(ImageView imageResourses) {

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mview.findViewById(R.id.imagefilesource);

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.word);


        }

        public void setPDF(ImageView imageResourses) {

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mview.findViewById(R.id.imagefilesource);

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pdf);


        }

        public void setimage(ImageView imageResourses) {

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mview.findViewById(R.id.imagefilesource);

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);


        }
                public String setImageURL(String url, PostUtils maa){

                url=maa.getImageUrl();

                    return url;

                }


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {


            case R.id.logut:


                Logut();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void Logut() {
        auth.signOut();
        finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a recyclerView, one method you should override is onBindViewHolder. Inside of that method is where you define the content of each element of the recyclerView.

So if you want to each row can be clickable,  think you need something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder postViewHolder, int i) {
  postViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //Definde what happend when the item is clicked
          //To identify which row, you can use postViewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        }
    });

}
```

Let me know if works.

Comment: I know that already defined the issue is how to detect  the imageUrl fro each item

Comment: I cant see you code clearly, but you have to define all the characteristics of the row on the recycler (here you define that each row has a imageUrl), and then you can send a list to the recycler with all data of all the rows. After that, in the onBindViewHolder, you set the imageUrl of that row, with the position of the list that corresponds.

This example maybe can help you.

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/